# JSF 2.0 - Convert view ID to URL

Tags: jsf-2, el

I want to convert a view ID into a URL using EL.

The purpose of doing this is to use an html `<form/>` tag to submit a form to a page using `GET` instead of `POST`. The form's `action` attribute needs to have a URL, unlike `<h:form/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This writes the outbound URL from a view ID via the servlet container in a single step:

```
<form action="#{facesContext.application.viewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(facesContext,view.viewId,null,false)}">
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `#{request.contextPath}` to dynamically inline the context path:

```
<form action="#{request.contextPath}/some.xhtml">
```

If you want to submit to the current view ID, get it by `#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId}`:

```
<form action="#{request.contextPath}#{facesContext.viewRoot.viewId}">
```

Or if you haven't mapped the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` for some reason, or you don't want to be dependent on its mapping and your container supports EL 2.2 (or JBoss EL), then use [`ViewHandler#getActionURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getActionURL%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
<form action="#{facesContext.application.viewHandler.getActionURL(facesContext, view.viewId)}">
```

Comment: Thanks. It's so obvious I feel like an idiot now. That is step one. The next step, I imagine, will be fairly easy: encode the URL using the servlet container. This is necessary because I'm rewriting URLs using Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter. I'll have a go at it myself now...

Comment: Ah right, after seeing your other answer I finally understand what you mean with "encoding". You just want to dynamically apply the `FacesServlet` mapping. This is absolutely not the same as URL encoding. I edited the answer to show a simpler way.

Comment: The documentation implies that our code should do the same, but in fact `getActionURL()` doesn't apply the `FacesServlet` mapping when I try it.